# Keras Dot giving positive cosine similiarity even when the vectors are opposite

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to see the dot functionality from keras. To my surprise for +ve as well as -ve expected cosine similiarities (-1 to +1), the cosine similiarity shown here is 0.9999. Are we not supposed to get -1 if vectors are orthogonally opposite like below example?

Tensorflow 2.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x=np.asarray([-1.,-1.,-1],dtype=float)
x=np.reshape(x,(1,3))
y=np.asarray([1.,1.,1.],dtype=float)
y=np.reshape(x,(1,3))
tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=-1,normalize=True)([x,y]).numpy()[0][0]
0.99999994
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really fell for that for a bit. You have

```
y=np.reshape(x,(1,3))
```

Should be,

```
y=np.reshape(y,(1,3))
```

Comment: Oops. Shame on me for doing such a silly mistake and posting here. Apologies and thanks together @thushv89